# Вернуть из функции массив на C

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Какой способ более правильный?

1. ```
   int *f() {
       int a[2] = {4, 5};
       int *p = a;
       p = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
       p[0] = a[0];
       p[1] = a[1];
       return p;
   }
   ```
2. ```
   void f(int *p)
   {
       // Память по адресу `p` выделена вне функции
       int a[2] = {4, 5};
       p[0] = a[0];
       p[1] = a[1];
   }
   ```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

Какой вариант будет предпочтительнее зависит от контекста. Если уже имеется некоторое семейство функций (к которому также можно отнести `f`), выделяющих память при вызове, то предпочтение имеет смысл отдать первому варианту: `int *f()`. Если функции упомянутого семейства работают с заранее выделенной памятью, то разумно использовать второй вариант: `void f()`. В любом случае, в документации должно быть описано кто является ответственным за освобождение той или иной памяти, адресуемой указателем.

При сравнении вариантов использования так же можно увидеть плюсы и минусы в обоих случаях:

- Вариант 1:

  ```
  int* ptr = f();
  use(ptr);
  free(ptr);
  ```
- Вариант 2а:

  ```
  int* ptr = malloc(...);
  f(ptr);
  use(ptr); 
  free(ptr);
  ```
- Вариант 2b:

  ```
  int ptr[] = {...}; 
  f(ptr);
  use(ptr);
  ```

Первый вариант явно требует работы с динамически выделяемой памятью. Во втором варианте помимо этого можно использовать и стековую или глобально выделенную память. Отказ от `malloc`/`free` может дать существенный прирост производительности в определенных ситуациях.

Вариант 1 по сравнению с 2b для пользовательского кода будет короче, т.к. не требует явно выделять память, и переменная `ptr` инициализируется по месту.

Из стандартных сишных функций для первого варианта вспомнилась пока только `strdup`. Хотя, думаю, должны быть и ещё варианты. Но функций второго типа  однозначно больше.

Answer (score 4):

В программировании, только один критерий  правильности. Это корректно работающий алгоритм. В обоих случаях алгоритм работает одинаково.